Female doctor working as an Ortjopedic surgeon
I am a resident and about to start my training in Orthopedic Surgery. For the Operation Theather i have to scrub in; this means i have to wear a half sleeve shirt and wash my hands for sterilisation purposes and after thag ill be given a full sleeves gown and göoves to wear. For the period of being scrubbes in my hands will be seen, will it be allowed for me to do so? Considering there is no other way due to sterilisations purposes.
Apart feom that during residency i am also obliged to look and treat all patients includinc men. Is this field allowed for me in islamic point of view. Please answer me as soon as possible because these questions and unclear Situations are making me very depressed and frsutrated. I have gone through a lot of exams and hard working to reach till this point but now i dnt want to spend my life in sonething that can be source of sinn  for me
